# Title in Google different from source code?

Tags: seo, metadata, title

I've been doing a job for a client recently and I noticed something strange about one of their competitors sites.

The title and description listed in Google is different to the one that's in the pages source code, I know this isn't just a case of index lag, because the sites been like this for quite awhile.

I'm thinking it must be some kind of SEO trick, because the title in the source code has about 3 or 4 keywords in it, where as the title that displays on Google is just the name of the company and 1 keyword.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe it's testing for the google bot and serving it different code ?

Comment: It's okay I've figured out what was going on, seems Google takes preference of the <meta name="title" content="" /> over <title></title>

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. It is a well-known phenomenon.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean its normal? Your answer sounds like you read the title not the rest of the question.

Comment: I read the whole question. Google is replacing titles for some time now. The particular circumstances under which this happens are not known.

Comment: There is not much I can tell you because this behavior is not documented. The rules and reasons are not known. Except for the reason that is always given: It's good for the user.

Comment: I actually found the answer out myself, Google was choosing to list the meta tag title, not the one between the title tags <title></title>, Google's algorithm probably chooses which ever one it's feels is most relevant to the page.